# Handling Data Time parse Error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to handle this error if my API output is **"datePosted": ""**

i'm using https://pub.dev/packages/intl

[image]

**Output when the data isNot = ''.**

[image]

Comment: Either use `try`-`catch` and catch the `FormatException` or use [`DateTime.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html) and handle a `null` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
void main() {
  String date = 'invalid-date';
  String dormattedDateTime = formatDate(date);
}

String formatDate(String date) {
  try {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date);
    return DateFormat('yMMMD').format(dateTime);
  } on FormatException {
    return '';
  } catch (e) {
    return '';
  }
}
```